# Is the a way to remove the "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" at web.config module tag in ASP.net WebForms without losing it's functionality?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms

So, i have a webforms asp.net application that i compile all it's code and basically leaves no file at the folder, except for the "bin" folder and the "web.config" file. All pages, handlers and everything else really is delivered by the HttpApplication implementation, even images and other resources.

To do that i publish using the complete merge option, and i just need to keep the "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" tag at the web.config, and it works.

So my question is; is there anything that i can implement on the code side to allow the same result and remove that tag from web.config? Is it possible to not have a web.config module tag at all, and still run all requests through the managed code?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This feels like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Might be, but it's a conceptual question - allow the program to behave the same even if the web.config file is removed and need to be recreated - leaving the web.config with only the implementation specific configurations rather then a major working option - still, my question isn't about a problem, but a concept to see if it's possible (since i found nothing on my search about it)

Comment: PS: thanks for the XY Problem link - i enjoyed the read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible. That's strictly an IIS setting, so you won't be able to move it to your code.

However, if you also own the IIS server configuration, you can move this setting up to `applicationHost.config` in a `location` tag, instead of `web.config` of your web app, which leaves the latter as clean as you wished.

Comment: nice to know that; i imagined i could not be done, but choose to consult stack first to see if i was missing anything - really, that's a good idea also (move "up" to applicationHost) - as i said to mason, one thing would prevent any problems if the web.config was deleted and need to be recreated - and that settles it

Comment: @SammuelMiranda If you've got web.config files being removed willy nilly, you've got bigger problems. You should have an established deployment pipeline, and no-one should be removing those files randomly.

Comment: i understand that man, np - again, i'm simplifying things it's not an actual problem - i'm wrapping up all my codes and seeking conceptual knowledge to make better decisions in design - knowing the "un-obvious" tends to be very helpful when trying to do that